# Take half width in 3 columns CSS grid layout

Tags: css, css-grid

Can we create a layout like in below image by CSS grid?

[image]

Comment: Use 6 columns instead of 3.

Comment: Some popular CSS frameworks use a 12 column grid, because it gives you flexibility with layouts.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, WFM! It also requires to know how to span N columns without knowing at advance where it started; `grid-column auto / span N` works for me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a 6 columns grid, and set `grid-column: auto / span 3;` for the first two elements and `auto / span 2` for the rest of them:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-auto-rows: 32px;
}

.grid span {
  background-color: steelblue;
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

.grid span:nth-child(1),
.grid span:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```